# does comparing models make sense?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

Let's say I have 3 factors `f1`, `f2` and `f3` and fit these models

```
m1 <- lmer(y ~ f1 + (1|sub))
m2 <- lmer(y ~ f1*f2 + (1|sub))
m3 <- lmer(y ~ f1*f2*f3 + (1|sub))
```

Does it make sense to compare the models with `anova(m1,m2,m3)`? Or would you first test every single step

```
m1 <- lmer(y ~ f1 + (1|sub))
m2 <- lmer(y ~ f1 + f2 + (1|sub))
m3 <- lmer(y ~ f1 + f2 + f3 + (1|sub))
m4 <- lmer(y ~ f1*f2 + f3 + (1|sub))
etc
```

I suppose the second example is correct. But what if `m1` and `m2` do not differ statistically? Does that mean I should not include `f2` and `f3` in my model? But what if for example `f2` and `f3` are significant in model `m3`? This happens with my real data, for example `m1` is not significantly different from `m2`, but `f1` interacts significantly with `f2` when the interaction is added to the model. I just don't see the point in comparing models then.

Comment: compare for what purpose? if it's forecasting performance then you compare anything with anything

Answer (score 4):

It would be better to perform the omnibus test for all interactions together, i.e.,

```
fm_additive <- lmer(y ~ f1 + f2 + f3 + (1 | sub))
fm_inter <- lmer(y ~ f1 * f2 * f3 + (1 | sub))
anova(fm_additive, fm_inter)
```

and from it see if any of the interactions seem to offer anything when including them in the model.

Answer (score 3):

The second approach you describe is called stepwise regression and is not a good idea. You should base the inclusion of variables first and foremost on theoretical basis. If you believe `f1`, `f2` and `f3` are only meaningful if their interaction with one another is included, then the first method for comparing them would be better.

Do note that a model with more parameters always produces a better fit. However, a better fit is not a better model, as it may overfit the sample, poorly predicting new observations.

It might benefit you to read e.g. [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20836/176202) (and its the many warnings about stepwise regression expressed in the comments and highest rated answer) or the answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/317649/176202).

Comment: OP isn't necessarily trying to select a model, they may simply be trying to test hypotheses about the effects of different variables in the model ...

Comment: Thanks @Frans Rodenburg but the first method seems strange to me because `m1 <- y ~ f1` and `m2 <- y ~ f1*f2` differ not only in that `m2` has `f2` in addition to `f1` but also that `m2` has all interactions that are not included in `m1`. So it seems that we are comparing very different models, does that make sense?